# Deploy every build to a server using Gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've set up my own Gitlab server with one project and a Gitlab runner configured for it. I'm new to continuous integration server and therefore don't know how to accomplish the following.

Every time I commit to the master branch of my project I would like to deploy the repository to another server and run two shell-commands there (`npm install`and `forever restartall`)

How would I do this? Do I need a runner on the machine which the project is deployed to as well?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could use gitlab-ci and gitlab-runner [runners.ssh] to deploy to single or mutiple servers.

the flow:

```
(git_project with yml file)  --> (gitlab && gitlab-ci) --> (gitlabrunner) ---runners.ssh---> (deployed_server,[deploye_server2])
```

1. you need register gitlab-runner to gitlab-ci and set the tag to delpoyServer on gitlab web .
   /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml:

   ```
    [[runners]]
     url = "http://your.gitlab.server/ci"
     token = "1ba879596cf3ff778ee744e6decedd"
     name = "deployServer1"
     limit = 1
     executor = "ssh"
     builds_dir = "/data/git_build"
     [runners.ssh]
       user = "you_user_name"
       host = "${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP1}"
       port = "22"
       identity_file = "/home/you_user_name/.ssh/id_rsa"


   [[runners]]
     url = "http://your.gitlab.server/ci"
     token = "1ba879596cf3ff778ee744e6decedd"
     name = "deployServer2"
     limit = 1
     executor = "ssh"
     builds_dir = "/data/git_build"
     [runners.ssh]
       user = "you_user_name"
       host = "${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP2}"
       port = "22"
       identity_file = "/home/you_user_name/.ssh/id_rsa"
   ```

the runner.ssh means, the runner will login into `${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP1}` and `${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP2}`, then clone the project to `builds_dir`.

2. write the yml file
   for example:
   .gitlab-ci.yml

   ```
   job_deploy:
     stage: deploy
     tags: delpoyServer1
     script:
       -  npm install &&  forever restartall
   job_deploy:
     stage: deploy
     tags: delpoyServer2
     script:
       -  npm install &&  forever restartall
   ```
3. set the your gitlab-runner to `delpoyServer1` and `delpoyServer2`tags in 'http://your.gitlab.server/ci/admin/runners'

   - when you push you code to gitlab
   - the gitlab-ci server will parser your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in your project, choose a runner with the tags: `deployServer1` or `deployServer2`;
   - the `gitlab-runner`with the deployServer1 tag  will login  into `${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP1}` and `${the_destionation_of_deployServer_IP2}` with ssh , clone the project to `builds_dir`, then  execute you script: npm install &&  forever restartall.

link:

- [gitlab-runner register](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/runners/README.html)
- [runners.ssh](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md)

Comment: Hi! With ssh executor the runner will use the Deployment keys? I always get the same error:gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.3.3 (6220bd5)
WARNING: image is not supported by selected executor and shell
WARNING: services is not supported by selected executor and shell
Using SSH executor...

ERROR: Build failed: open /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file or directory

Comment: Yes, your should config your ssh key file with your real path of ssh private key(e.g: `/home/change_me/.ssh/id_rsa` . Before that  you must append the  the public key content  to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the runner server's.
The ssh key is between runner server and deloy servers :
`(private ssh key  in runner server) --> (deploy servers with ssh  public key)`

Comment: thanks for the help, was very helpfull. Now it´s working :)
But for my runner work proprely i remove this line `identity_file = "/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa"`. When i put the previous line the runner doesn´t work and show the same error message,  in my  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file i put `AuthorizedKeysFile /home/user_name/.ssh/authorized_keys` and `HostKey /home/user_name/.shh/id_rsa`. Why the runner doesn´t work with the identity_file? i´m doing something wrong?

Comment: In short we must  make  the runner connect to deploy server with some way.  I this case we use ssh-path. If your runner work properly when remove identify_file , Did you config the password  ? You can get the detail from (the link)[https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md]. If not, I really cannot understand that unless you show your topology of CI  servers and your configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the first deploy it run npm install and forever start OK. But once I made a new commit, the CI deploy and I got an error `failed to remove node_modules/...`. Do you have any idea about my situation?

Answer (score 23):

You should be able to use [gitlab-ci.yml documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ci/yaml/README.html) to add a separate `build` stage into your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

You will need some sort of deploy service (like `capistrano` or similar), or a webhook that'll initiate a deployment.

I.e. something like:

```yaml
---
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

job_runtests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm test

job_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - curl -X POST https://deploymentservice.io/?key=
```

Gitlab CI will iterate through each stage it finds, running them sequentially. If a stage passes, then it moves on to the next.

Unfortunately Gitlab CI can't do deployment directly (although you can install the [`dpl`](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl) Ruby Gem and call that in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like so:

```yaml
job_deploy:
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=my-app-staging --api-key=$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY
only:
  - master
```

for example)

Comment: I have a question, the --api-key is attached to my account in heroku, so if I have an open sourced project in gitlab anyone could deploy to my heroku servers. How can I make sure that only MY gitlab.ci can deploy with my api-key?

Comment: You can add private project variables in Gitlab settings - leave the .gitlab-ci.yml file to reference (literally) `$HEROKU_STAGING_API_KEY` and then in Settings -> CI/CD for your project, add a protected environment variable.