# How to start a service using GitLab runner and prevent it from stopping?

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm going to deploy simple Spring Boot application using GitLab CI server. My `.gitlab-ci.yml` is as follows:

```
stages:
  - build_and_test
  - deploy

web_server_build_and_test:
  stage: build_and_test
  script:
    - mvn clean package

web_server_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mvn clean package -Pprod
    - service gitlab-runner-test stop
    - cp target/*.war /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
    - chmod +x /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
    - service gitlab-runner-test start
```

And the `deploy` stage produces the following output:

```
$ service gitlab-runner-test stop
Stopped [13247]
$ cp target/*.war /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
$ chmod +x /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war
$ service gitlab-runner-test start
Started [21177]
```

However, I'm unable to load the application since the service has been stopped once runner finishes the stage:

```
$ service gitlab-runner-test status
Not running (process 21177 not found)
```

My service scripts delegates actual work to the assembled `war` package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
export MODE=service
export APP_NAME=gitlab-runner-test
export PID_FOLDER=/var/run/gitlab-runner-test


/var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war $*
```

Moreover, when I'm starting service by hands (`service gitlab-runner-test start`) it remains running even after user session has been closed.

I'm not sure, what is the root of the problem - Spring Boot startup script, GitLab configuration, my service scripts or something else?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with GitLab CI multi runner version 0.5.0 (c38415a).

**UPD:**

Upgrading runner to version 1.0.1 (cffb5c7) does not solve the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem is. Use [`nohup`](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) to launch a process without killing it when the parent exits. So `- nohup service gitlab-runner-test start` or `nohup /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war $*`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Why it's a bad idea to do it...

As its documentation clearly states, the [GitLab Runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner) "runs **tests** and sends the results to GitLab".

And as tests should start and stop in a timely manner, the runner is designed to kill all created processes after finishing each build.

So it's not a *bug* that your service is killed, it's a *feature*. ;)

GitLab CI documentation [recommends using dpl](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/examples/deployment/README.html) for **deployment**.

dpl is a project that enables you to deploy your app at various PaaS providers, such a Google App Engine, Heroku or Elastic Beanstalk.

So it fires some requests to some REST APIs or pushes some other data through the internets and its process nicely exits.

So doing what you want to do actually requires some hacking - overriding the default runner behaviour. And you should not do it as a long-term solution because it may stop working with some runner/gitlab update.

## ...but if you insist, then here's the how-to :)

In your case, when you want to actually deploy and run the app on your runner's host itself, we need to use two hacks:

- don't use the default `shell` runner executor but `ssh` and make the executor ssh to itself (inspired by [michael's solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33840561/2693875) (please upvote his answer too if upvoting mine!),
- disown the process that is being run by the init script ([Joe's solution to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26420299/2693875) (again - please upvote it!)

Ok, so here are the instructions:

1. Make sure you can SSH from your runner host to itself with a SSH private key in `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`, without passphrase, without confirming the fingerprint. `ssh localhost` run by `root` should work non-interactively.
2. Edit your gitlab-runner's config file, `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` to make it look like this:

   ```
   [[runners]]
     name = "your-runner-name"
     url = "https://<your_gitlab_instance_fqdn>/ci"
     token = "<your_project_CI_token>"
     tls-ca-file = ""
     executor = "ssh"
     [runners.ssh]
       user = "root"
       password = ""
       host = "localhost"
       port = "22"
       identity_file = "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
   ```

(The runner will reload itself after saving the config file)

3. Edit your service script so the process it will create will NOT be a child of the init script and it won't open stdin, stdout and stderr:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java
   export MODE=service
   export APP_NAME=gitlab-runner-test
   export PID_FOLDER=/var/run/gitlab-runner-test


   /var/gitlab-runner-test/gitlab-runner-test.war $* <&- >&- 2>&- & disown
   ```

Test by retrying last build or making a commit to your project repo.

---

PS I tested my solution with an init script looking like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

start() {
  # Completely disowned process, not a child
  # Credits: Joe at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26420299/2693875
  sleep 99999 <&- >&- 2>&- & disown
  exit 0
}

stop() {
  echo "doing nothing"
  exit 0
}

echo "running on $HOSTNAME..."

case "$1" in
  start)
    start
    ;;
  stop)
    stop
    ;;
  *)
    echo $"Use this options $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
esac
```

..on Ubuntu 14.04 with gitlab-multi-runner v. 1.02 and GitLab CE 8.5.0.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to check your solution as soon as I come to work. Is it necessary to run runner as a root?

Comment: So, if deploying though GitLab CI is a bad idea, shouldn't I write a custom provider for dpl instead?

Comment: Why should someone use `dpl` instead of `eb deploy` for Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Probably because `dpl` provides unified interfaces for many backends, not only AWS but also GCP, Azure, Heroku etc., @Chloe.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution, posted by @GregDubicki works just perfectly and contains explanations for each step, I've end up with a solition with monitoring service, which restarts my service after each build.

This approach has the following advantages:

1. You should not start runner under `root` user
2. You should not care about processes, killed by runner
3. (+ bonus) You have a monitoring system now!

Comment: I'm insterested in the monitoring service you built. Is it on github? Have you come across anything like it elsewhere? Seems like starting an application would be an important step in CICD that doesn't seem to be heavily covered.

Comment: Well, this was about 3 years ago, things have changed a lot since then, I am not currently working on that project so I may not remember the exact details of the CI/CD process evolution. Though I do remember the monitoring system I used, it was [`mmonit`](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/ConfigurationExamples) - worked fine and solved the case with restarting the service (all you need is to deploy new files and stop the service - the monitoring system will restart it for you). However, after some time I changed the script to use `dpl`-like approach. It was not exactly `dpl` because ...

Comment: ... It was not exactly `dpl` because we did not use cloud servers, therefore our custom solution worked fine. The pipeline was as simple as: build the war, `scp` it to the server and run `deploy.sh` script on that server over `ssh`. The `deploy.sh` was capable of creating new services if needed (say if we are deploying a test branch we need to create a new service and then destroy it), preparing application config (db, host, port, etc.) and so on. I talked to a developer from that company a few months ago, and they are now planning to switch to Docker + k8s (or similar deployment platform).

Comment: Currently I am using k8s for my new projects, however if you are not using Docker I suggest you to use a separate server for CI builds and deploy your apps (even dev and staging environments) to a separate server with a `dpl`-like approach. Though if your company is small and you do not have a separate server for applications yet, you can use a monitoring tool to restart your applications - but this is not an ideal solution.