# Gitlab - Google compute engine Continuous delivery

Tags: swift3, gitlab, google-compute-engine, continuous-deployment, vapor

What I am trying to do is to enable Continuous delivery from GitLab to my compute engine on Google Cloude. I have Ubuntu 16.04 TSL running over there. I did install all components needed to run my project like: Swift, vapor, nginx.
I have manage to install Gitlab runner as well and created a runner whcihc is accessible from my gitlab repo. Everytime I do push on master the runner triggers. What happen is a failure due to:

`could not create leading directories of '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/2bbbbbd/0/Server/Packages/vapor.git': Permission denied`

If I change the permissions to `chmod -R 777` It will hange on `running` for `build` stage visible on gitlab pipeline.

I did something like:
`sudo chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /home/gitlab-runner/builds`
`sudo chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /home/gitlab-runner/cache`
but this haven't help, the error is same `Permission denied`

Below you have my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
before_script:
  - swift --version

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

job_build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
  - vapor clean
  script:
  - vapor build --release
  only:
  - master

job_run_app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy a  API"
    - vapor run --name=App --env=production
  environment:
    name: production

job_run_frontend:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy a  Frontend"
    - vapor run --name=Frontend --env=production
  environment:
    name: production
```

But that haven't pass to next stage eg. deploy. I had waited more then 14h for that but with out result. 
And... I have few more questions:

1. Gitlab runner creates builds under location `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/` in this location every new job have own folder. for eg. `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/2bbbbbd/` in which is my project and the commands are executed. So what happens when the first one is running and I do deploy new version? the ports are blocked by the first instance and so on?
2. If I want to enable `supervisor` how do I do that with this when every time I deploy folder is different?
3. Can anyone explain or show me or point me to tutorial how do Continuous deployment with out docker?

Comment: How did you solve your permission issues? Facing the same problem myself.

Comment: I did use `chmod -R 777` that works for me. I know it's not perfect solution but for testing purpose it's fine. Howover it was hanging on `build` due to the process it's not finishing. For CD I am aiming dpl now

Comment: After some work I got `build` to work on gce. Also looking into dpl now for CD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to start a service using GitLab runner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088983/how-to-start-a-service-using-gitlab-runner-and-prevent-it-from-stopping)

Thanks to long deep search I finally found an answer! The full article can be found above.

Briefly GitLab CI documentation recommends using dpl for deployment. Gitlab runner run test and process should end. The runner is designed to kill all created processes after finishing each build. The GitLab runner is unable to perform operations outside the catalogue.