# Deploy a build to another server with gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to do a deploy to another internal server that happens after each commit. I tried the steps mentioned here but they aren't working for me: [Deploy every build to a server using Gitlab CI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33768537/deploy-every-build-to-a-server-using-gitlab-ci/33840561#33840561)

I get the following error message:

> gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.2.0 (3a4fcd4)
>
> Using SSH executor...
>
> ERROR: Build failed: dial tcp: lookup ${MY_INTERNAL_PROJECTS_SERVER} on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:52735->[::1]:53: read: connection refused

/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml:

```
concurrent = 2

[[runners]]
  name = "deploy_on_projects_server"
  limit = 1
  url = "https://${MY_INTERNAL_GITLAB_SERVER}/ci"
  token = "701299841717071d3abfb45d91a56a"
  executor = "ssh"
  builds_dir = "/home/${USER}/test"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "${USER}"
    password = "${PASSWORD}"
    host = "${MY_INTERNAL_PROJECTS_SERVER}"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
build:
  tags: ["deploy_on_projects_server"]
  script:
    - echo "build"
```

On my gitlab server I changed the user to gitlab-runner and successfully used ssh to login to my projects server. So that is working fine.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or how I can fulfill my need?

Comment: I don't know what you set `MY_INTERNAL_PROJECTS_SERVER` too, but the runner cannot resolve it's address. Is it a domain or just an host you put into `/etc/hosts`?

Comment: Never mind, it tries to lookup the IP, but it seems that the DNS server is not set up correctly - It tries to access the DNS server at localhost. Check you `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. But why does it work when I do it manually via ssh?

Comment: What exactly worked?

Comment: I changed in the runner config the domain to it's IP address and then the build worked.

Comment: Do you use a `~/.ssh/config` file by any chance? The runner is executed as a different user so it wouldn't have access to the ssh config in your home directory